# Bash Drop Down Menu from contents of Array (CGI-bin/apache2)

Tags: arrays, bash, drop-down-menu, apache2, cgi-bin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Output of command in Bash script to Drop-down box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914426/output-of-command-in-bash-script-to-drop-down-box)

I have an array in a bash script. I have apache2 configured so I can run cgi/bash scripts in my cgi-bin directory, and they will display like a webpage.

Is there any way to take each element of the array and make it one result in a drop down box on the page?

For example, if my array looked like:

```
a[0] = "255" 
a[1] = "254" 
a[2] = "253"
a[3] = "252"
a[4] = "251"
```

I would want the dropbox to look like (lol, ASCII)

```
 _____
|255  |
|254  |
|253  |
|252  |
|251  |
 -----
```

Any suggestions? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can write a bash for loop to do everything.  This just prints out the elements:

```
for i in `seq 1 "${#x[*]}"`; do
    echo "|${x[i]} |"
done
```

To get the alignment correct, you need to figure out the max length (one loop) and then print out the terms:

```
# w will be the length
w=0
for i in `seq 1 "${#x[*]}"`; do
    if [ $w -lt ${#x[$i]} ]; then w=${#x[$i]}; fi
done
for i in `seq 1 $((w+2))`; do printf "%s" "-"; done
printf "\n"
for i in `seq 1 "${#x[*]}"`; do
    printf "|%-$ws |\n" ${#x[$i]}
done
for i in `seq 1 $((w+2))`; do printf "%s" "-"; done
printf "\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly simpler (but more verbose) solution:

```
box()
{
    local -a a=(1 20 300 4000 50000)
    local -i w=0

    for i in "${a[@]}"
    do
        [ $w -lt $i ] && w="${#i}"
    done

    printf -- '-%.s' $(seq $w)
    printf -- '---\n'

    for i in "${a[@]}"
    do
        printf -- '|%-'$w's |\n' $i
    done

    printf -- '-%.s' $(seq $w)
    printf -- '---\n'
}
```